# How do I get an Arduino GSM shield to send a smswhen a button is pressed?

Tags: arduino, sms, gsm

I need to design the arduino board like this. when I press button 1 the GSM shield sends an SMS to a specified phone number and when I press button 2, it sends another different message to that specified phone number. I am a newbie to arduino. Please it is a great help if you can give the code for me. The sending message must be started after the relevant button press. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sendSMS example in the Arduino IDE
File->Examples->GSM->sendSMS